# Difficulties proving these two inequalities

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Given  that  $f(x)=g(x)h(x)\in F[x]$  such  that  $E/F$  is  a  splitting  field  of  $f(x)$ and  $B/F$  and  $C/F$  are  splitting  fields  of  $g(x)$  and  $h(x)$  respectively and  both  contained  in  $E$ . $B\cap C=F$.

Then $$Gal(E/F) \cong Gal(B/F)\times Gal(C/F)$$
Now  to  arrive  at  this  result  I  have  to  prove  two  equalities  and  ,combined,  they  will  give  the  desired  result  .

They  are

$$1)\ \ Gal(E/B)\cap Gal(E/C)=Gal(E/{B\lor C})$$
$$2)\ \ Gal(E/B)\lor Gal(E/C)=Gal(E/B\cap C)$$

For  the  first  one if  $$\sigma \in Gal(E/{B\lor C})$$  then  $\sigma $  is  an  automorphism  that  acts  as   identity  on   $B\lor C$  which  is  the  compositum  of  $B$  and  $C$ and  contains  both  of  them  so  must  act  on  $B$ and  $C$  as  identity .  So  $$\sigma \in Gal(E/B)\cap Gal(E/C)$$ and $$Gal(E/{B\lor C})\subseteq Gal(E/B)\cap Gal(E/C)$$

Conversely  let $$\tau  \in  Gal(E/B)\cap Gal(E/C)$$
Then  $\tau $ acts  as  identity on  both  $B$  and  $C$  and  hence  on  their  *compositum*  as  *compositum*  is  generated  by  the  union   $B\cup C$ so  $$\tau \in Gal(E/{B\lor C})$$ Thus $$ Gal(E/B)\cap Gal(E/C)\subseteq Gal(E/{B\lor C})$$

or, $$ Gal(E/B)\cap Gal(E/C)= Gal(E/{B\lor C})$$

Is  there  any flaw  in  my  logic  $?$

Then  for  the  second  one  I  am  stuck . 
If  $$\sigma \in Gal(E/B)\lor Gal(E/C)$$
then $$\sigma=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\gamma_{i} +\sum_{i=1}^{m}\tau_{i}\ \ where\ \  \gamma_{i}\in Gal(E/B)\ \ and\ \ \tau_{i}\in Gal(E/C)$$  Then  clearly  $\sigma$  fixes  the  elements  that  are  in  $B\cap C$ .  So  I  have  $$ Gal(E/B)\lor Gal(E/C)\subseteq Gal(E/B\cap C)$$

Here  I  have  almost  reached  the  end  but  I  cannot  prove  the  converse  of this  inequality . I  need  help  with  that .

Thanks.

Comment: Note that $Gal(E/B)\vee Gal(E/C)=Gal(E/B)Gal(E/C)$ since these groups are normal in $Gal(E/F)$.

Comment: What to do next? Still confused.